# how count the number of digits of telephone numbers?

Tags: java, count, numbers, digits

easy for usual numbers, but telephone numbers can start with 01-...., as an example, 01234
is basically 1234 for java, right?

So I can't divide by 10 recursively to find out how many digits there are.
is there any different way to find out how many digits there are ?

thanks in advance.
ps.: no regex if possible

Comment: have the phone number as a `String`?

Comment: What you've already tried so far?

Comment: @jhamon I got it as an int

Comment: what prevents you from converting an int to string?

Comment: If you're reciving `012345` as an int then you can't do anything about it, it will be represented as `12345` and you can't know if there was `0` at the beginning or not.

Comment: @Amongalen (unless, for example, they are phone numbers for a country where all numbers begin with zero-nonzero, e.g. the UK, in which case you can add one).

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the phone number is a string,

```
String pn = "049-4912394129" // that's a random value
```

then you could iterate in that string and check if a character is indeed a number

```
int count = 0;
for(char c : pn.toCharArray()){
  if(Character.isDigit(c))
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Or: `pn.codePoints().filter(Character::isDigit).count()`.

Answer (score 0):

As you phone number is an int, you don't need to bother with regex and every locale phone number patterns.

Simply convert your `int`phone number to a String. Then you can easily get the string length.

```
int myIntNumber = 1234;
String myStringNumber = String.valueOf(myIntNumber);

int length = myStringNumber.length();
```

Comment: @AndyTurner, I don't get your comment. OP wants to know the number of digit in his number to know if there is missing leading zero. Probably to do zero-padding later

Answer (score 0):

*this could easily be done with a lambda*

```
"049-4912394129".codePoints().filter( Character::isDigit ).count();  // 13
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a number that represented by a String object then:

```
public int getNumberOfDigits(phoneNumber) {
   int count = 0;
   for (int i = 0, i < phoneNumber.length(); i++) {
       if (Character.isDigit(phoneNumber.charAt(i))) {
           count++;
       }
   }
   System.out.println("Number of digits: " + count);
   return count;
}
```

If you are talking about a number that represented by an int then simply 
convert it to String before using it like so:

```
String phoneNumber = String.valueOf(phoneNumberInInt);
```

I assumed you DO want to count the zeros as a digit because you are not summarizing the value of them, so they do have a meaning when you talk about how many digits are there.